# How to edit the database query in Joomla?

Tags: database, joomla

I want to create a login form for my system which is student management system.

As we all know, the login form is already created by the Joomla. I want to use the form but when user insert the username and password, I want the form select the username and password from my database which is "STUDENT".

What I should do? Should I import my database into the database that created by Joomla? I don't know how and where to find the query in Joomla file.

Answer (score 0):

You can import through sql the student users into the joomla user table or create manualy, and then assign them specific user groups from backend, so you can make profiling for student

Comment: which file in joomla file that have any query mysql?